# vb .net using excel automation to paste data into opened workbook

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, office-automation

Is it possible to paste data into an already opened worksheet using office automation from vb.net? (I done it using oledb but is very slow.)

```
        Dim Folder As String = "C:\Users\gm1\Desktop\"
        Dim Filename As String = "Raw2Eng.xlsx"
        Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Folder & "\" & Filename & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
        Dim MyConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)

        MyConnection.Open()
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
        cmd1.Connection = MyConnection
        cmd1.CommandText = "DROP TABLE [Sheet2$A1:E1027]"
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd1.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [Sheet2$A1:E1027] (HiResAngle FLOAT, CH2 FLOAT, CH4 FLOAT, CH5 FLOAT, CH6 FLOAT)"
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

        For j As Integer = 0 To TrimmedSegmentSize - 1
            sb = New StringBuilder
            sb.Append("INSERT INTO [Sheet2$A" & 1 & ":E" & j + 1 & "] (HiResAngle, CH2, CH4, CH5, CH6) values ( '")
            sb.Append(eng(i, j, 0)) : sb.Append("' , '")
            sb.Append(eng(i, j, 1)) : sb.Append("' , '")
            sb.Append(eng(i, j, 2)) : sb.Append("' , '")
            sb.Append(eng(i, j, 3)) : sb.Append("' , '")
            sb.Append(eng(i, j, 4)) : sb.Append("' )")
            cmd1.CommandText = sb.ToString
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        MyConnection.Close()
```

Comment: It seems you have an surrouding loop (with the i variable). What does it do ?

Comment: Apart form the declaration (1st 4 rows) the code will repeat i times. So output will vary as I iterate through the 1st dimension of the 3D array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDb is way faster than automation.
Show us your code, may be there is another problem.

[EDIT]
If you really want to use automation (because you want to keep the workbook opened), you may read this article : [How to transfer data to an Excel workbook by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306022/en-us)

Comment: Hi Dude Pascalou. Please see my oledb code. I need to overwrite old data and as delete isn't allowed I drop-create table. The code works but to insert 1024 rows takes about 30 seconds if the workbook is open. Any suggestions how to improve the code?

Comment: I tried on closed workbook, the insertion reduces to 2 seconds. But I need 'live update' on opened workbook.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my code? If not, is there a more efficient way I could automate the data transfer from vb .net to excel while the target workbook is open?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code... I've edited my message to give you an help link.

Comment: I've already read this guide but the code presented here will create or open existing workbook then save changes. I guess my question is: can excel automation connect to already opened workbook? I appreciate your time, thank you for your help!

Comment: ...and the anwser is yes with late binding. Instead of using `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` you may use `GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`. See : http://word.mvps.org/faqs/interdev/earlyvslatebinding.htm

Comment: You are right, it works! I will add a comment later about performance in case others are interested. Many thanks for your help! (sorry, I'm not allowed to vote as I have lass than 15 reps)

Comment: Transfer time is 62 ms for 1024 x 5 table.